# Apache Tika, cannot retrieve 'subject' metadata value

Tags: java, metadata, apache-tika

I am using java and i am trying to extract some metadata with apache tika, but i cannot extarct the expected value for the 'subject' metadata. The file is a jpg image. Here is my code:

First i am parsing the file like this:

```
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToExtract);   
        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();  
        ContentHandler contentHandler = new BodyContentHandler();  
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata(); 
        parser.parse(inputStream, contentHandler, metadata, new ParseContext());
```

and then i am trying to print these:

```
    metadata.get(Metadata.AUTHOR)                           -->  "MyAuthor"
    metadata.get(TikaCoreProperties.CREATOR)                -->  "MyCreator"
    metadata.get(TikaCoreProperties.TITLE)                  -->   "MyTitle"
    metadata.get(Metadata.SUBJECT)                          -->   **null**
    metadata.get(TikaCoreProperties.KEYWORDS)               -->   **null**
```

So, i get correctly all the values and i get null value for the subject. The metadata were added manually by me (right click->properties, windows OS).

[image]

Am i doing something wrong?

---

PS: Note that "TikaCoreProperties.KEYWORDS" is another way to retrieve the subject according to apache tika documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Tika tries to return consistent metadata across all file formats. It shouldn't matter if one format calls it `Author`, another `Creator`, another `Created By` and another `Creator[0]`, Tika maps those all onto a consistent key. Typically, those keys are based on well known external standards, such as Dublin Core

If you want to see the mappings that Tika applies to Microsoft Office documents, you'll need to look in [SummaryExtractor](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/SummaryExtractor.java). If you want to know what all the metadata keys and values are that Tika can extract from a given file, either use the `tika-app` cli tool with `--metadata`, or call [names()](https://tika.apache.org/1.5/api/org/apache/tika/metadata/Metadata.html#names%28%29) on the [Metadata object](https://tika.apache.org/1.5/api/org/apache/tika/metadata/Metadata.html) to get the list of metadata keys Tika found.

Comment: But i am not passing random Strings to the library methods. The code i am using is based on the apache Tika Documentation (https://tika.apache.org/1.5/api/org/apache/tika/metadata/Metadata.html). So, since the subject field is not empty, either i am using the wrong keyword (Metadata.SUBJECT...), or the library is not capable to retrieve the value. Any insights about this?

Comment: What does the Tika-App CLI tool report with `--metadata` for your file?

Comment: Sorry i didn't see your comment. The tool does not retrieve any subject value also.

Comment: I've just create a word document (.doc) with a Title, a Subject and Keywords. Saved, ran the tika app against it, and I got back my test subject entry: `cp:subject: SUBJECT subject SUBJECT` . I can only suggest you raise a bug and upload the problematic file, as for the general case Tika is working just fine for me, and just fine in all the unit tests too...